# How can I find out what's going wrong with a ddev container, or see the logs?

Tags: ddev

I'm working on a project using [ddev](http://ddev.readthedocs.io) and I don't know how to troubleshoot things because they're hidden in the containers they run in. For example, I've tried `ddev logs` but it doesn't give me enough information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `ddev list` and `ddev describe` to get the general idea of what's going on, but then `ddev logs` is the first line of investigation. It gets the logs of the web container (both the nginx error log and the php-fpm error log, mixed together).

Extra approaches:

- You could probably (temporarily) remove any custom nginx/php/mysql configuration that you might have added to the project in the .ddev folder, as those are common culprits.
- Please make sure you're using the current docker images that match the ddev version you're using. I recommend deleting any "webimage" or "dbimage" lines in your .ddev/config.yaml.
- `ddev logs -f` will "follow" the web logs, so you can see what happens when you hit a particular URL.
- `ddev logs -s db` (or of course `ddev logs -f -s db` will show you the logs of the database container (MariaDB logs)
- Use `ddev ssh` (for the web container) or `ddev ssh -s db` (for the db container) to actually go in there and look around. The most important logs are in /var/log/ and /var/log/nginx.

You can even use `ddev logs` when a container has crashed or stopped for some reason, and figure out what happened with it.

Don't forget the [troubleshooting](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/basics/troubleshooting/) section in the docs.

Comment: I tried ddev ssh -s db then ls /var/log/mysql i got permission denied error i tried sudo i got sudo command not found

Comment: I like to download the log

Comment: I'm not sure if this is enough for you, but it might be: `ddev logs -s db >logs.txt` -anyway, add sudo to the db container as shown and you have full flexibility.

Comment: @rfay I believe it should be `dbimage_extra_packages: [sudo]` which can also be set with `ddev config --dbimage-extra-packages=sudo`

Comment: (Edited per @AlbertSkibinski's correction: If you want sudo in the db container (it's omitted for security reasons) use `dbimage_extra_packages: [sudo]`in your `.ddev/config.yaml` and `ddev restart` and you'll have sudo in there. However, `ddev logs -s db` will usually tell you everything.