# I did a "ddev start" and see "web service unhealthy" and "web service health check timed out"

Tags: ddev

I was working away on a ddev project that previously worked and now I can't get it going. `ddev list` shows "web service unhealthy" and `ddev start` shows "web service health check timed out". How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to understand what's up with the web container is to use `ddev logs`, see [How can I find out what's going wrong with a ddev container, or see the logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660210/how-can-i-find-out-whats-going-wrong-with-a-ddev-container-or-see-the-logs)

Most often these are the causes of web container timeout:

- [Edit 2018-05-16]: Inadequate docker resources. If you're running a few sites or have other things going on with docker, you'll want to raise the available memory from the default 2GB.
- Custom configuration. When debugging, please start out by removing any custom configuration from .ddev - custom nginx and php configuration are highly likely to be the problem.
- ddev version not matching the container versions in use. Starting with v0.18.0, ddev tries to get you to update the container versions in your config.yaml, but prior to that, if you had a "webcontainer" line in your config.yaml, ddev would use that container version instead of the one that it was built to use, and this could cause container timeout problems.